# Number of iterations in two nested while loops when a = n

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Suppose we have while loops:

```java
    a = 2n
    while(a < 9n^4)
    {
        b = 11n^2
        while(b > 1)
        {
            b = b / 7
        }
        a=2*a
    }
```

How do I find the number of iterations for both loops?

Comment: don't know what is the formula for this one but declare a variable outside the loops and increment it by one on every iteration of most inner loop

Comment: Mhh, I wonder .... do you know what `^` means?

Comment: ^ denotes exponents here.

Comment: No it doesn't. This is Java, not math. See [What does the ^ operator do in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1991380). Such details are important when you want to get the amount of iterations.

Comment: Lol alright, so let's assume it is. How would I go about estimating the iterations in each loop?

Comment: You should use Math.pow rather than use the xor operator improperly. Or else replace the java tag with algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the outer `while(a < 9n^4)` will work `x` times. Then we have an equation `2n * (2^x) < 9n^4 <==> 2^x < 4.5 n^3 <==> x < log_2 (4.5 n^3)`. The loop will break as soon as the condition is not satisfied, i.e. as soon as `x` is greater than that RHS, the loop breaks. This implies that there will be exactly `floor(log_2 (4.5 n^3))` iterations of it.

The inner cycle is (way) trickier in case you mean Java integer division, or very similar to the outer in case you mean just plain floating point division.

Answer (score 0):

```java
int iterationCount = 0;

a = 2n
while(a < 9n^4) {
    b = 11n^2

    while(b > 1) {
        iterationCount++;
        b = b / 7
    }
    
    a=2*a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically the first loop condition is 2n < 9n^4
-> 2^2 * a - > 2^3*a... so we have 2^m * 2n computations.
the second loop is 11n^4 / 7 computations.